# How to deploy unversioned files with TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I have a website organized like this :

- a server with all the code
- a server with all the other ressources like files/images

At this point I managed to get the source code from subversion, build it, and then deploy it (msbuild).

The thing is, my images are not versioned. So how can I do to take the images from our dev server to our build server ? What is the best way to put it into Team City ? I think that these files re some kind of artifact but I'm not sure (I don't understand very well this notion, the title "artifact" doesn't help).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to add your images and other resources into Subversion, then you can control their checkout as part of your deployment.

Comment: The problem is that you're right, but I'd love to avoid that, putting images in subversion is kind of bad in my mind. I'll wait if someone has a magical solution...

Comment: If the images are part of the application itself, then they should be in Subversion. Otherwise, it will be a maintenance nightmare trying to sync versions of the images with versions of your application.